# Configuring Route 53 and Elastic Beanstalk issues

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have a domain that I registered via Route 53. I have followed the steps to point the domain Alias to my Elastic Beanstalk instance. But, when I access my domain, I am receiving the default NGINX config index.html file. If I access the beanstalk URL, then it loads just fine.

Any thoughts on fixing this?

Comment: Which steps? Any link? Have you modified any settings on EB's nginx?

Comment: Ended up being an issue with my nginx config. Its important to include the correct server_name in the config :D

Comment: If you don't mind I could provide an answer based on the comments. Or you can answer your own question if you like?

Comment: I would love to get your perspective! I'll add any comments to your answer, if there are any. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: I provided an answer. There is not much to write about, thus if you want you can add further details in comments or your own answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was caused due to **misconfiguration of nginx**. Specifically, [server_name](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name) was not set to the custom domain.

The **solution** was to modify the nginx config and use custom domain in `server_name`, e.g.:

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
}
```